# ¿Cuándo un observable no ejecuta la función suscrita?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

He heredado el desarrollo de un frontal en Angular. Ahora mismo tengo que desarrollar una pantalla que muestre  datos de una lista, así:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of itemList; let i = index">
    <!--mostrar los datos-->
</tr>
```

Ahora bien, en el momento de crear un nuevo item, ocurre algo curioso. Esta es la función del componente que crea el item:

```
newItem() {
    this.itemService.insertMockItemData().subscribe(
        (resp) => {
            if (resp.created) {
                // vuelve a pedir los items para el usuario y los carga en el array
                this.loadItemList(resp.user.email);
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log('Error');
            // tratamos el error correspondientemente
        }
    );
}
```

*Disclaimer: he quitado muchas partes y nombres de la función por lo que es posible que falte algo*

El servicio simplemente llama al back:

```
insertMockItemData() {

    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiURL}path/topost/item`, {
      "id": "item",
    });
}
```

Esa URL devuelve un OK y efectivamente se crea el recurso, pero no se recarga la lista de recursos, ni se genera ningún error.

Para ser más específico, **parece como si no se estuviera suscribiendo ninguna función al observable que devuelve el servicio, o que este no emitiese valores.**

¿Hay que hacer algo extra para que este observable emita el valor? He leído por internet que los observables se ponen en `ngOnInit`. ¿Puede tener que ver?

Comment: y donde se modifican los datos para itemList es el objeto que debe tener los nuevos elementos.

Comment: @MiguelZarate No tengo muy claro a qué te refieres...

Comment: agrega un `*ngIf` al cargar y ocultas y muestras los datos nuevamente, asilo obligas a renderizar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondo aquí porque ya no puedo borrar mi propia pregunta. Al final el problema estaba en otro lado: toda la parte HTML de la pregunta está metida dentro de un formulario, el cual tiene un botón de submit para crear un nuevo item.

```
<form>
    <!--varias cosas-->
    <button class="btn" (click)="newItem()">
        <span>Nuevo item</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

El botón de submit disparaba un refresco de página que era lo que hacía que se perdiesen las suscripciones y no se viesen los logs.

Al final hemos optado por desactivar el botón con una variable bandera que esté activa mientras se hace la petición:

```
<form>
    <!--varias cosas-->
    <button class="btn" (click)="newItem()" [disabled]="isProcessingRequest">
        <span>Nuevo item</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con tan pocos datos es complicado estar seguro, pero creo que lo que pasa es lo siguiente: Angular, por temas de eficiencia, no intenta detectar cambios internos de los objetos. Si un componente tiene un objeto con propiedades y dichas propiedades son mostradas en su plantilla, sólo detectará cambios y re-renderizará la plantilla si la instancia del objeto es sustituida por otra, pero no si lo que cambias son sus propiedades.

Una solución un poco chapucera pero rápida y efectiva al trabajar con arrays es clonarlos al modificarlos:

```
addElement(elem)
  this.list.push(elem);
  this.list = this.list.splice();
}
```

Viendo tu código me falta la parte crítica para estar seguro al 100%, pero seguramente eso es lo que falta dentro del método que es llamado para añadir el elemento: `this.loadItemList(resp.user.email);`

Comment: A pesar de que es muy posible que eso sea un punto de fallo (porque sí que me faltaba hacer un `slice`), no es ahí. He puesto un `console.log` antes de llamar a `loadItemList` y no se hace log de nada...

Answer (score 0):

Quiero creer que tu log va justo debajo del load, y que lo que mandas por el log es el mismo load, es decir:

```
newItem() {
this.itemService.insertMockItemData().subscribe(
    (resp) => {
        if (resp.created) {
            this.loadItemList(resp.user.email);
            console.log(loadItemList);
```

Si es ese el caso no estas metiendo los datos al array, para tenerlos en tu loadItemList deberias hacer algo como :

```
newItem() {
this.itemService.insertMockItemData().subscribe(
    (resp) => {
        if (resp.created) {
            this.loadItemList.push(resp.user.email);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hola Mauricio, no es el caso. `loadItemList` es un método, que acepta una string (el email) y carga los datos.